# Cisco ASA - DHCP Relay doesn't seem to be working consistently

Tags: cisco, dhcp, cisco-asa

I'm having an issue where some users on one of our DMZ networks aren't getting a DHCP address from the Windows DHCP server on our internal interface.  Being that not everyone is affected is making this difficult to troubleshoot.  Below are the logs I'm seeing, any idea what to look into:

```
Apr 13 13:28:11 172.x.x.x Apr 13 2011 13:28:11: %ASA-7-710005: UDP request discarded from 0.0.0.0/68 to dorms:255.255.255.255/67
Apr 13 13:28:12 172.x.x.x Apr 13 2011 13:28:12: %ASA-7-710005: UDP request discarded from 0.0.0.0/68 to dorms:255.255.255.255/67
Apr 13 13:28:14 172.x.x.x Apr 13 2011 13:28:14: %ASA-7-710005: UDP request discarded from 0.0.0.0/68 to dorms:255.255.255.255/67
```

ASA DHCP Configuration:

```
dhcprelay server <ip address of dhcp server> inside
dhcprelay enable dorms 
dhcprelay setroute dorms
dhcprelay timeout 360
```